# Как правильно вставить значение val из localstorage в input, чтобы сработало умножение данных

Tags: jquery, angularjs, localstorage

Значение val из input помещаем localstorage, после обновления страницы данные из localstorage добавляются обратно к input, но формула умножения данных не работает, какое есть решение данной проблемы?

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
<div check-storage class="uk-container uk-container-center uk-margin-top">
    <div class="costInt" data> = {{ val * 21 }}</div>
    <input class="number-pole" val="0" ng-model="val" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" type="number" data />
    <button class="reset">reset</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
angular
  .module("demo", [])
  .controller("DemoCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.val = 0;
  });

angular
  .module('demo')
  .directive('checkStorage', function() {
    return {
      link: function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.number-pole').each(function(ndx) {
            $(this).attr('data', 'Numb' + (ndx + 1));
          });
          if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            $('input').each(function() {
              var getData = $(this).attr('data');
              var localContent = localStorage.getItem(getData);
              if (localContent !== null) {
                $(this).val(localContent);
              }
              $(this).bind('click change keyup focusout', function() {
                localStorage[getData] = $(this).val();
              });
            });
          }
          $('.reset').on('click', function() {
            localStorage.clear();
            $('.number-pole').each(function() {
              angular.element(this).val(0);
            });
          })
        });
      }
    }

  });
```

пример [**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/d6BLVi?p=preview)

Comment: ничего не пойму, вроде используешь angular, а записываешь параметры через jquery? Где `$scope` где работа с внутренней моделью? Тебе нужно пересмотреть матчасть. У тебя есть контролер, а ты подписываешься на нажатие кнопки `reset` с помощью jquery. Забудь про него. Ты на ангуляре пишешь друг)

Comment: спасибо за совет, учу angular) внимательно изучу твой пример

Comment: @Василий Барбашев а как можно применить ваш пример к такому варианту? http://plnkr.co/edit/6pVY1oCm5SQcvFwjSmLJ?p=preview

Comment: Да, конечно можно. Просто надо придумать как генерировать и считать, это вопрос больше математический. Мой пример в принципе это и делает.

Comment: @Василий Барбашев буду признателен за помощь, т.к. с данным примером и мучаюсь

Comment: После обеда попробую посмотрю :)

Comment: @Василий Барбашев спасибо :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37707/discussion-between-sashatexb-and--).

Comment: доступа к чату на работе у меня нет, проксятник блочит

Comment: @Василий Барбашев,  жду с не терпением Ваш вариант  :)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/wcn35Y8wWyV6v80xjq1G?p=preview проверяй, единственное что не сделал, это когда ты поле отключаешь не считать значение. Ну это можно тебе на закуску оставить ;)

Comment: Но я все не проверял, он может сумму ещё не правильно считать

Comment: @Василий Барбашев все супер, огромное при огромное спасибо! добавил только для последнего столбца следующее  {{ datafields.cost * val[$parent.$index][$index].cout * kurs | number : 0 }}, осталось дописать фильтр цен и готово, буду вникать в ваш код, для понимая

Comment: @Василий Барбашев, а такой вопрос, кнопка <button ng-click="reset();">Сбросить</button> не должна выходит за рамки контроллера PostsCtrl?

Comment: @Василий Барбашев Консоль по кнопке reset(): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: а я её и не делал, код не менял, но ты можешь дописать его в таком же виде как и считается сумма всех элементов, только там будет не присвоение `summ+=`, а зануление `$scope.val[i][j].cout = 0;`. А по поводу кнопки, ты можешь обработчик выкинуть в `$rootScope` и уже общаться через него. Он будет доступен везде. Т.е ты в любом контроллере можешь присваивать метод $scope.reset = $rootScope.reset; и обрабатывать (это например)

Comment: @Василий Барбашев, спасибо огромное, все сделал)))) Благодаря Вам начал обширнее понимать angularJS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так сделал я

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
  <div check-storage class="uk-container uk-container-center uk-margin-top">
    <div class="costInt" data> = {{ summ * 21 }}</div>

    <input ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4]" ng-init="init(i, $last);" ng-change="valChange(i);" class="number-pole uk-width-2-10" val="0" ng-model="inputs[i]" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" type="number" />

    <button ng-click="reset();" class="reset">reset</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
link: function($scope) {
  $scope.init = function (i, last) {
    var local = localStorage.getItem('Numb' + i);
    $scope.inputs[i] = parseInt(local) | 0;
    if (last) {
      $scope.summ = $scope.getSumm();
    }
  };

  $scope.getSumm = function () {
    var summ = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.inputs.length; j++) {
      summ += $scope.inputs[j];
    }
    return summ;
  }

  $scope.valChange = function (i) {
    var identy = 'Numb' + i;
    var value = $scope.inputs[i] + '';
    // id - мы передаем вторым параметром как Numb1
    localStorage.setItem(identy, value);
    $scope.summ = $scope.getSumm();
  }

  $scope.reset = function() {
    localStorage.clear();
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.inputs.length; j++) {
      $scope.inputs[j] = 0;
    }
    $scope.summ = 0;
  }
}
```

Конечный смысл, n-ное количество полей, создаются, каждое значение при изменении сохраняется в localStorage. При обновлении страницы данные записываются обратно в поля, считается сумма и умножается на 21. На кнопку Reset обнуляются все поля и сумма. Если число в каком либо поле < 0, то сумма не считается и равна NaN.

**Ну и живой пример:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/i2QlLBTQXyKKdhVuUGIS?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Все очень просто, как правильно заметили в комментариях: к результату биндятся данные из ангуляра, а выставляются они, при загрузке, через jQuery.

Ангуляр просто не знает, что далее следует обновить view.

Как пример решения задачи, которая возникла из-за не правильного использования инструмента:

нужно вызвать `change()` после функции `each`.

Но это лишь усугубит возможные ошибки при дальнейшем использовании/расширении кода.

Лучше использовать возможности ангуляра, как в соседнем ответе.

[Плохой рабочий пример](http://plnkr.co/edit/c6zCMQEHe4nVpSpsSdTy?p=preview)

Comment: спасибо и за плохое решение, Вы правильно сказали "при дальнейшем использовании/расширении кода"